# Callback in Coffee Script

Tags: javascript, callback, coffeescript

I have the following function in coffeescript :

```
@get_person = (person_id) ->
  $.ajax '/people/'+person_id,
    type: 'GET'
    dataType: 'text'
    error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        $('body').append "AJAX Error: #{textStatus}"
    success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        $('.right-bar').html(data)  ->
            alert 1
            $('#interaction_filter').chosen()
```

The part of

```
$('.right-bar').html(data)  ->
```

works perfectly, but the call back below that, does not execute. What am I doing wrong? Nothing is shown in the console either.

Comment: What is this callback supposed to do? What is the JS code that you expect?

Comment: It basically calls the chosen (https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails) on a select box. I have other select boxes where the content is not loaded via AJAX and they load fine. 
When I type  $('#interaction_filter').chosen() on the console later however, it works fine.
So I assumed it's because the data is still being loaded into the DOM when the .chosen was being called and hence I added it as a call back so it would wait till the "data" was fully loaded into the DOM

Comment: Please see my answer bellow.

Comment: @MichaelVictor: But  `.html()` does not offer a callback, it is synchronous. And your notation is wrong anyway, as it did call the jQuery object as a function, which should have thrown an exception. It only is important that the `.chosen()` call is placed inside the `success` callback.

Comment: for some reason, my accepted answer has been deleted because there was not enough explanation, please I edited an existing answer, just look and let me know if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot wirte:

```
$('.right-bar').html(data) ->
```

the syntax doesn't allow that, you can instead sure this

```
$('.right-bar').html (data) ->
```

as shown here: http://api.jquery.com/html/

**please consider adding the space between html and (data) ->**

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not what the OP wants. Please explain what it does.

Answer (score 0):

After running it through the CoffeeScript compiler I get the following output:

```
this.get_person = function(person_id) {};

$.ajax('/people/' + person_id, {
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'text',
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    return $('body').append("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    return $('.right-bar').html(data)(function() {
      alert(1);
      return $('#interaction_filter').chosen();
    });
  }
});
```

I believe what you wanted to do was chain the calls to html(). If so, it would look like this:

```
@get_person = (person_id) ->
    $.ajax '/people/'+person_id,
        type: 'GET'
        dataType: 'text'
        error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
            $('body').append "AJAX Error: #{textStatus}"
        success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
            $('.right-bar').html(data).html ->
                alert 1
                $('#interaction_filter').chosen()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.
    
     $('.right-bar').html(data).html 

works though! but not the alert 1

Comment: @MichaelVictor Sorry I think I got that one slightly wrong. I assume you wanted $.ajax to be called inside the get_person() function since person_id is used in the code. I have edited the above post to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

Coffeescript is whitespace sensitive, so you need to indent the body of your callback to make it part of that function.

As Anthony pointed out the first few lines of your original code compile to

```
this.get_person = function(person_id) {};

$.ajax('/people/' + person_id, {
....
```

In other words, assign a function that does nothing to `this.get_person`, and then make an ajax call.

Assuming you wanted the ajax call to happen within the function then try:

```
@get_person = (person_id) ->
    $.ajax '/people/'+person_id,
        type: 'GET'
        dataType: 'text'
        error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
            $('body').append "AJAX Error: #{textStatus}"
        success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
            $('.right-bar').html(data)  ->
                alert 1
                $('#interaction_filter').chosen()
```

Indenting the `$.ajax` line makes it part of the callback function.

If you want to experiment more here's the solution on [Try Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%40get_person%20%3D%20(person_id)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%24.ajax%20'%2Fpeople%2F'%2Bperson_id%2C%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'GET'%0A%20%20%20%20dataType%3A%20'text'%0A%20%20%20%20error%3A%20(jqXHR%2C%20textStatus%2C%20errorThrown)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24('body').append%20%22AJAX%20Error%3A%20%23%7BtextStatus%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20success%3A%20(data%2C%20textStatus%2C%20jqXHR)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24('.right-bar').html(data)%20%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24('%23interaction_filter').chosen())

Comment: The `.html(data)  ->` part is actually what does not work. He successfully executed the ajax call, that must be a markup problem in the question.

Comment: Not any more, there was in the original question before it was edited to add an indent on the 2nd line.